# Implementing Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have to implement Spring integration, the requirement is that When I get a request I need to split it and call two seperate web services to process the request and then get the response back from both the services and combine it into one and return the response. I am not sure how to just wanted to know if someone had a clue.

And also if this is possible can I make the calls simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have enough theoretical knowledges.

You need:

- Splitter
- Aggregator
- Router
- Executor Channel

So, please, read these docs:

- http://martinfowler.com/books/eip.html
- http://www.manning.com/fisher
- http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html

Comment: Its true that am short of theoretical knowledge but am also short of time.. I just want to know if its possible get split my request and pass it to 2 seperate services at the same time